# Node express API not get in response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I have created a node-express API.

```
router.get('/getData', function(req, res) {
let data = { 
    title: 'Message Effectiveness – Bar Chart – 1Q',
    chartData: [
    {
        title: 'Motivating',
        data: [.75, .45, .45, .41, .37, .35, .30, .20, .20]
    },
    {
        title: 'Believable',
        data: [.75, .45, .45, .41, .37, .35, .30, .20, .20]
    },
    {
        title: 'Differentiating',
        data: [.75, .45, .45, .41, .37, .35, .30, .20, .20]
    },
    {
        title: 'Effectiveness ^',
        data: [.75, .45, .45, .41, .37, .35, .30, .20, .20]
    },
   ]
 }

 res.json(data);
})
```

And I request using fetch like this

```
fetch('http://localhost:5050/api/getData').then(response => {
  console.log(response)
}).catch(err => {
 console.error('Network error', err)
})
```

In Network tab I got the same JSON object send from server. In console log of resonpse it print below things....

[image]

How can I use the JSON data that send from the server?

Comment: Have you reviewed [the documentation for the `Response` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) you’ve got? Are you confused on anything there?

Comment: `.then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data))`

Comment: You can print your data using console.log() or you can convert your data which is in JSON format to string using JSON.stringify() and show it on the console. Remember, the data that you are fetching on the frontend will be displayed on your browser's console and not on your backend/command console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the actual data, you need `response.json()` like this to actually read and parse the body of the response:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5050/api/getData').then(response => {
  return response.json();
}).then(data => {
  // use the data here
  console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('Network error', err)
});
```